# instantiate generic type in generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I have such a structure

```
void Main()
{
    var lol = ActionClass.GetTestTuple<Request, Response, RequestCallInfo>("lol", "user");
    lol.Dump();
}

public class ActionClass
{
    public static Tuple<TRes, TInfo> GetTestTuple<TReq, TRes, TInfo>(string resultMsg, string userName)
    where TReq : BaseRequest, new()
    where TRes : BaseResponse, new()
    where TInfo : CallInfo<TReq>, new()
    {
        var response = new TRes { Message = resultMsg };
        var eventsInfo = new TInfo();
        eventsInfo.Data.UserName = userName;

        return new Tuple<TRes, TInfo>(response, eventsInfo);
    }
}

public class Request : BaseRequest
{
}

public class Response : BaseResponse
{
}

public class RequestCallInfo : CallInfo<Request>
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
}

public class CallInfo<GenericType> : BaseCallInfo where GenericType : BaseRequest, new()
{
    public GenericType Data { get; set; }

    public CallInfo(GenericType x)
    {
        Data = x;
    }
}

public class BaseCallInfo
{
    public string CallItem { get; set; }
}

public class BaseRequest
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class BaseResponse
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and when I execute it, I get `UserQuery.CallInfo<UserQuery.Request> does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments,`

So i tried this way

```
public static Tuple<TRes, TInfo> GetTestTuple<TReq, TRes, TInfo>(string resultMsg, string userName)
    where TReq : BaseRequest, new()
    where TRes : BaseResponse, new()
    where TInfo : CallInfo<TReq>, new()
{
    var response = new TRes { Message = resultMsg };
    var eventsInfo = new TInfo(new TReq { UserName = userName });
    eventsInfo.Data.UserName = userName;

    return new Tuple<TRes, TInfo>(response, eventsInfo);
}
```

but i'm getting `'TInfo': impossible to provide arguments when instantiating a type`

How can I pass an instance of `TReq` to `TInfo` and keep only the parameter constructor in `CallInfo<GenericType>`?

Comment: OT: signature constraints are in the specs for c#7. i really hope they don't ditch it again.

Answer (score 1):

The `new()` constraint only requires that a generic type have a public parameter-less constructor; there is no way to specify specific construct signatures on a generic type / constraint in C#.  Given that, the compiler cannot know what constructors would be available by callers, so you can't instantiate a generic type using constructor parameters.

So you could use reflection here if you would like, but this solution seems simpler based on the code you've provided:

```
var eventsInfo = new TInfo() { Data  = new TReq { UserName = userName } };
```

Comment: It would be so nice if we could declare constructors on Interfaces.

Comment: @MatthewWhited That can be easily worked-around with factories

Comment: @CodingGorilla it keeps saying that I need the parameter less constructor. Is there a way to make it work and keep the constructor with the param?

Comment: Not saying it can't; it could be much cleaner with constructors on interfaces.

Comment: @Phate01 I'm not sure I understand, you can have both a parameter-less constructor **and** the constructor with the param.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @CodingGorilla No, I wanna keep only the param constructor

Comment: @Phate01 then you violate the `new()` constraint that specifies that `TInfo` must have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: I wonder, how much this would be sufficient : Activator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @icbytes That would _compile_ , but since there's still no guarantee that the actual class has a constructor that matches the desired signature, it's susceptible to errors at runtime.

Comment: Activator looks up the ctor, that matches best I thought, So I believe in most cases this would also do the job, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @icbytes What if it didn't have anything other than the required public parameter-less constructor?  That's the only thing that you can **guarantee** exists at run time.

Comment: Right, and You get those object back, not more, is this not the aim in the end ? Or missed I some crucial point ?

Comment: @icbytes Well if all you're going to do is call the parameter-less constructor, what does Activator give you?  It's much easier to just use `new TInfo()`, right?

Comment: No, that the OP does not want. He does not want to call the default ctor, but if no other matches, then this will be called, like a fallback.

Comment: @icbytes CreateInstance does not do that automatically.  You would have to look for a constructor that matches, and if one does not exist, then call the parameterless one.  It's _possible_ but messy.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Activator.CreateInstance` method.

Working solution:

```
public class ActionClass
{
    public static Tuple<TRes, TInfo> GetTestTuple<TReq, TRes, TInfo>(string resultMsg, string userName)
        where TReq : BaseRequest, new()
        where TRes : BaseResponse, new()
        where TInfo : CallInfo<TReq>
    {
        var response = new TRes { Message = resultMsg };
        var eventsInfo = (TInfo)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TInfo), new []{ new TReq() });
        eventsInfo.Data.UserName = userName;

        return new Tuple<TRes, TInfo>(response, eventsInfo);
    }
}

public class BaseCallInfo
{
    public string CallItem { get; set; }
}

public class BaseRequest
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class BaseResponse
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Request : BaseRequest
{
}

public class Response : BaseResponse
{

}

public class RequestCallInfo : CallInfo<Request>
{
    public string Item { get; set; }

    public RequestCallInfo(Request x) : base(x)
    {

    }
}

public class CallInfo<GenericType> : BaseCallInfo where GenericType : BaseRequest, new()
{
    public GenericType Data { get; set; }

    public CallInfo(GenericType x)
    {
        Data = x;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As several people have commented on the other answer, this will **fail at runtime** for any class that does not have a matching constructor signature.  While this will work given the specific code the OP provided, this is a very bad practice (IMO) as it presents potential bugs to another implementer of the `CallInfo<TReq>` in the future who isn't aware of this code.